# calling Python module from VBA/xlwings

Tags: python, vba, xlwings

I'm working on an excel/xlwings tool to practice my mental math, using old python scripts I used to run off a command line. When trying to run my VBA macro, I get the following error:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Training_factoring'
```

I'll offer something of a checklist to give this request some context:

- I'm using Anaconda3 and the spyder IDE
- My PYTHONPATH is C:\Users\benms\Anaconda3, and my Interpreter path
  is C:\Users\benms\Anaconda3\python.exe
- My excel file is located in the same directory as my python module
- I have imported the xlwings bas file
- My RunPython call does follow the syntax guidelines from the docs, and my python module has the xw.Book.caller() piece per the docs

Here are my code samples:

#### VBA macro

```
Sub PracticeStart()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Response As Long

    Do While True
        RunPython ("import Training_factoring; Training_factoring.DistributionTwoDigit()")

        Response = InputBox("Answer? ")
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("practice").Range(i + 2, 1).Value = Response
        i = i + 2
    Loop

End Sub
```

#### Python module

```
def DistributionTwoDigit():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    x = random.randrange(10, 99, 1)
    y = random.randrange(10, 99, 1)
    i = 0

    i =+ 2
    wb.sheets[0].range("A1").value = "Distribution (Two-Digit)"
    wb.sheets[0].range(i+1,1).value = '{}*{}'.format(x, y)

    RunAnswer()
    wb.sheets[0].range(i+3,1).value = (x*y)

    wb.sheets[0].range(i+4,1).value = '-------------------------------'
    x = random.randrange(10, 90, 1)
    y = random.randrange(10, 90, 1)
```

Comment: I would advise you to start with `xlwings quickstart myproject`, test this out to make sure it works, then change it step by step to your code.

Comment: Thanks - myproject works perfectly. I changed some things around in my RunPython function and am now getting a syntax error...any help here would be appreciated!
Error
---------------------------
  File "<string>", line 1

    import sys, os; sys.path.extend(os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'C:\Users\benms\OneDrive\Documents\GMAT')).split(';')); import UDFs-GMAT;UDFs-GMAT.DistributionTwoDigit()
                                                                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please open an issue on GitHub for these kind of questions: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues

Comment: Thx I'll open there.